# does my dba know what he is doing?

Tags: java, encryption, sha

I am new to all the encryption, hashing etc.
I received email from my dba, telling me to read admin un, password from .properties file and it looks something like this:

```
ldap.provider.admin.password=fc34f78f665b60c5b99bad0ee1b228269e10e9cdd81c1a
```

Then in his email he specifies:

```
ldap.provider.admin.password is actual password encrypted with “SHA256”.
```

Telling me in my java programm I will have to decrypt this password in order to be able to use it.

Is it me or does he have it confused with crypto hash algorithm?
Can I actually get it decrypted?

Comment: Doesn't sound like he does (source: every question that uses the words "hash" and "decrypt" together). Maybe ask him how you're supposed to "decrypt" the hash.

Comment: What is the purpose of reading this hashed password?  Is it to authenticate a user to your program, or to authenticate your program to some other service?

Comment: @rgettman I am using it for authentication:          env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,adminName);
          env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,adminPassword);

Comment: I suspect your DBA is having a joke with you.  The whole point of SHA256 and other hash functions like it is that you CAN'T invert it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Encrypted" is a misleading term, because that implies that it can be decrypted.  Something transformed with the "SHA256" algorithm is actually cryptographically *hashed*.  There is no "decrypt" functionality for a cryptographic hashing algorithm.

But you can still use it.  When a user submits a password, perform "SHA256" on the user's submitted password, and compare it with the stored, hashed password.  By the looks of the string above, you may need to convert the hash output to a hex string to compare it.

Additionally, you may first need to find out if a salt is applied to the hash (additional random content added on a per-user basis to increase security).  If so, then you'll need to apply the salt to the user's submitted password before hashing it.

Comment: I think the context is that OP wants to programmatically access some service via LDAP (so the program has to supply authentication). The latter part of your answer takes the perspective of the LDAP service that verifies the credentials.

Comment: @delnan "Telling me in my java programm I will have to decrypt this password in order to be able to use it."  It appears from the question itself that the Java program will attempt to read a `.properties` file to use the hashed password.

Comment: That is my reading too: The Java program will read the hash from `.properties` and will need to use the password that was hashed. I differ on how to use it: It seems obvious from the question that the Java program wants to authenticate *itself* to some other program using this password.

Comment: @delnan Either way, you can't decrypt SHA-256-hashed output.

Comment: Absolutely. That's not what I contest.

Comment: I am using simple authentication, which requires me to provide clear password. This is why I need the password to be in clear text to be able to authenticate.